# PHP Yii2 - How to make Client-side core validators use $() instead of jQuery()

Tags: php, yii2

Im using a template that uses an old version of jQuery. Everything works perfectly except for client side validation.

Any ideas on how to have the validators use $() instead of jQuery()?

Comment: Don't think it is possible. Why would you need that? jQuery relies on window.jQuery.

Comment: Use wrapper like so `(function($){ //code })(jQuery);`